# ImageCol in DataGridView doesn't resize my Bitmap image from URL

Tags: vb.net, image, datagridview

I have a function which I found on here it works for me  but it doesn't shrink the png image to 10,10 size as it suppose to do and after it populate my cell it is actually size as 250px like from web ([png image from web](https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/12882/large/Secondary_Symbol.png?1628233237))

**My Function:**

```
    Public Shared Function GetImage(Url As String) As Image
    Try
        If (Not ImageList.ContainsKey(Url.Trim)) Then
            Dim req As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(Url)
            Dim response As WebResponse = req.GetResponse()
            Dim stream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
            Dim img As Image = Image.FromStream(stream)
            stream.Close()
            ImageList.Add(Url.Trim, img)
            '
        End If

        Return ImageList(Url.Trim)

    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.Print(ex.Message)
        Return New Bitmap(10, 10)
    End Try
End Function
```

**DatagridView code:**

```
   Dim _inj_ThumbLink As String = jsonResult(0)._thumb
   Dim _inj_Thumb As Image = GetImage(_inj_ThumbLink)
   Form1.dgvMain.Rows(3).Cells(1).Value = _inj_Thumb
```

[picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXQZW.png)
[picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bnprf.png)

Comment: [DataGridViewImageColumn.ImageLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewimagecolumn.imagelayout)

Comment: @Jimi thx man 'column.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Zoom' it works!

Comment: @Jimi Do you know what should I do if I'm scraping API JSON with crypto chart prices and I have for example 10 'subs' (Sub1 = for BTC, Sub2 for ETH etc..) and each will have to be assigned to one Row, but I don't like to load DataGrid view with 10 rows, I rather will open form and blank DataGridview and when I hit 'button1' it will scrape my json 10 subs and create for each sub new row automatically, thx

Comment: This has nothing to do with the current question or the code you posted. Post another question with code that describes what you're doing with whatever data you have.

Answer (score 0):

Following [Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi)'s suggestion in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71103480/imagecol-in-datagridview-doesnt-resize-my-bitmap-image-from-url/71104389#comment125690708_71103480)

> [DataGridViewImageColumn.ImageLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewimagecolumn.imagelayout)

I used

```
column.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Zoom
```